# Quickbooks OAuth - Getting started guide and API reference - where can I find them

Tags: xml, api, quickbooks

QuickBook OAuth docs and API. I want to implement OAuth for Quickbooks. I am looking for a getting started guide and the latest API docs.

QuickBooks uses OAuth. I have used OAuth before, but never with quickbooks.
I want a QuickBooks guide to using OAuth. For code, I will use Google Apps Script (JavaScript). I am not sure if I will need to use XML, or if code exists for JS/GAS.

I did find this:
https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/samples/readme.html

But it does not look like the best place to start.

Eddy.

Comment: Quickbooks developer - getting started: http://developer.intuit.com/ipp.html
API: https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0060_Reference  I am still starting out, but looks like these are where to start. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](https://code.intuit.com/sf/projects/qb_javascript_sdk/) and [this link](https://www.quickbase.com/api-guide/index.html) are the best resources I have been able to find for the  QuickBooks Javascript SDK. I have been unable to find anything else in my time working on it.